# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/app/p2p_app/p2p_app.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnjingle_peerconnection_so.so" not found

Tags: android, apk, preload, firmware

I need to preload 3rd party app to my firmware.
But when I execute this preloaded app, there is a error about referencing libraries in this apk.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/app/p2p_app/p2p_app.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnjingle_peerconnection_so.so" not found
```

When I unzip this apk(using apktool d), and check the lib folder, there is libraries.

I tried to unzip and copy libraries to /system/app/p2p_app/lib/arm/, and It works.

But the other 3rd party app is ok, even if I didn't extract and copy libraries to /system/app/.

How can I fix this? How can I guide to 3rd party app developer to preload to my firmware?

My firmware's android version is 7.0, sdk is 24.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := p2p_app
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := p2p.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

please please please let me know why.
This issue try to kill me now.